# What does it mean when no HTTP code is returned

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I'm trying to evaluate why some of our attempts to load a page are failing and for the most part, we get standard codes back but in a small percentage of cases we get no code at all. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: Do you mean you get no *response* at all?  Or that you get a header and there's just no response code in it?  Or it just hangs?  Also, what's serving these pages?  Are they static, dynamic, etc?

Comment: Turns out I set the open timeout low enough that I wasn't reaching the actual HTTP timeout. It's fine--I handled this case in my code "gracefully".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know 3 reasons:

1. Many webservers can execute `closesocket` with out responce.
2. Many developers ignore most of the features and protocol codes for HTTP when develop their web-servers. This is because all modern HTTP is methods POST and GET and Codes 403, 404, 200.
3. Bugs

Comment: IMHO 1 and 2 would be specific instances of 3 - the spec is quite clear. "Many webservers" - ???? citation?

Comment: Yeah, many. Popular webservers (nginx, apache, lighttpd...) near 1% of total count. Many developers write their webservers for one day, or one project..